# Converting string to ObjectId fail randomly

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I have some trouble with converting string to ObjectId in loopback.js.
Some times it's inserted as a string, so the relations and filters doesn't work (GUID field). Example in database :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a3d023fe1dfe3cd6fae101"),
    "GUID" : "59a3d023f82383384ea87e40",
    "username" : "John Doe"
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a3d0f3fe1dfe3cd6fae104"),
    "GUID" : ObjectId("59a3d023f82383384ea87e40"),
    "username" : "John Doe"
}
```

The GUID field is an existing ID from an other loopback/Mongo application. And you can see it's the same GUID in the 2 documents, i runned twice the same code and the second time it worked..
The code i use :

```
data.user.GUID = new ObjectID(data.user.GUID);
data.project.GUID = new ObjectID(data.project.GUID);

return Promise.all([
    app.models.user.upsertWithWhere({
        GUID: data.user.GUID
    }, {
        GUID: data.user.GUID,
        username: data.user.username
    }),
    app.models.project.upsertWithWhere({
        GUID: data.project.GUID
    }, {
        GUID: data.project.GUID,
        name: data.project.name
    })
]).then((result) => {
    // console.log("USER", result[0]);
    // console.log("PROJECT", result[1]);
    return result;
});
```

I really don't understand what's happening, if you can help me please ! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am one of LoopBack maintainers.*

I am afraid LoopBack is still not able to correctly handle `ObjectID` in all cases. Here are few things you can try to see if it fixes the problem you are encountering:

1) Enable `strictObjectIDCoercion` flag in your model configuration ([docs](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb#strictobjectidcoercion-flag)).

```
// common/models/project.json
{
  "name": "Project",
  // ...
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "strictObjectIDCoercion": true
  }
}
```

2) Add [loopback-datatype-objectid](https://github.com/BoLaMN/loopback-datatype-objectid) to your application and define your `GUID` properties as `"type": "objectid"`. See [this comment](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1874#issuecomment-304450459) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I'm currently testing with a lot of occurence and for now the bug didn't happened. But i'm not sure about the interest of `strictObjectIDCoercion` flag ? Does it help in this case ? According to the doc, it's more restrictive about the conversion to ObjectId, won't this make the conversion more unstable with a correct ObjectId ?

Comment: I am afraid I am not an expert on MongoDB connector. I read a bit more on strictObjectIDCoercion and I think you are right that it will make conversion to ObjectID more restrictive. But maybe it's a good thing because then all your GUID fields be stored as a string? It would be best if you could open a GitHub issue and describe steps how to reproduce this problem, if/when you happen to reproduce the bug again in the future.